# How to configure the STM32103 for CAN and remapping the pins to PB8 and PB9

Tags: stm32, can-bus

I am trying to, at this stage, simply send a transmission using CAN on the STM32F103 V8T6.  The chip is implemented on a board that was customized by my company.  Looking at the schematic I see that the CAN Tx and Rx pins were remapped to PB9 (Tx) and PB8 (Rx).  All that being said, I have been able to use LoopBack mode successfully (using the latest example from STM "V3.5.0") but have have NOT been able to get Normal mode working.  Can someone please let me know if they see an obvious flaw in my initial configuration?!  I have included only the code related to configuration and left out the transmission function call.

```
int main (void)
{

RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_AFIO, ENABLE);

RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);

RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_CAN1, ENABLE);



NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;

NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = USB_LP_CAN1_RX0_IRQn;

NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = CAN1_RX0_IRQn;

NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;

NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;

NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;

NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);



 GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;


/* Configure CAN pin: RX */

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_8;

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IPU;

GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);


/* Configure CAN pin: TX */

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_9;

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;

GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);


// Remap2 is for PB8 and PB9

GPIO_PinRemapConfig(GPIO_Remap2_CAN1 , ENABLE);


}
```

Here is my transmit function

```
void CAN_TransmitMyMsg(void)
{
  CAN_InitTypeDef        CAN_InitStructure;
  CAN_FilterInitTypeDef  CAN_FilterInitStructure;
  CanTxMsg TxMessage;
  uint32_t i = 0;
  uint8_t TransmitMailbox = 0;
  uint8_t status = 0;

  /* CAN register init */
  CAN_DeInit(CANx);
  CAN_StructInit(&CAN_InitStructure);

  /* CAN cell init */
  CAN_InitStructure.CAN_TTCM=DISABLE;
  CAN_InitStructure.CAN_ABOM=DISABLE;
  CAN_InitStructure.CAN_AWUM=DISABLE;
  CAN_InitStructure.CAN_NART=DISABLE;
  CAN_InitStructure.CAN_RFLM=DISABLE;
  CAN_InitStructure.CAN_TXFP=DISABLE;
  CAN_InitStructure.CAN_Mode=CAN_Mode_Normal;

  /* Baudrate = 125kbps*/
  CAN_InitStructure.CAN_SJW=CAN_SJW_1tq;
  CAN_InitStructure.CAN_BS1=CAN_BS1_2tq;
  CAN_InitStructure.CAN_BS2=CAN_BS2_3tq;
  CAN_InitStructure.CAN_Prescaler=48;
  CAN_Init(CANx, &CAN_InitStructure);

  /* CAN filter init */
  CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterNumber=0;
  CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterMode=CAN_FilterMode_IdMask;
  CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterScale=CAN_FilterScale_32bit;
  CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterIdHigh=0x0000;
  CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterIdLow=0x0000;
  CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterMaskIdHigh=0x0000;
  CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterMaskIdLow=0x0000;  
  CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterFIFOAssignment=0;
  CAN_FilterInitStructure.CAN_FilterActivation=ENABLE;
  CAN_FilterInit(&CAN_FilterInitStructure);

  /* transmit */
  TxMessage.StdId=0x11;
  TxMessage.RTR=CAN_RTR_DATA;
  TxMessage.IDE=CAN_ID_STD;
  TxMessage.DLC=2;
  TxMessage.Data[0]=0xCA;
  TxMessage.Data[1]=0xFE;

  TransmitMailbox=CAN_Transmit(CANx, &TxMessage);

  //wait until CAN transmission is OK
  i = 0;
  while((status != CANTXOK) && (i != 0xFFFF))               
  {
    status = CAN_TransmitStatus(CANx, TransmitMailbox);
    i++;
  }

}
```

This resource has been helpful, but ultimately insufficient.

[STM32F103 microcontroller CAN messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195033/stm32f103-micro-controller-can-messages)

Thanks!

Daniel

Comment: Well, first, does the actual bus work, (cables, terminators etc)? Is anything actually transmitted, (storage scope, CAN anlyser etc)?  What errors are reported, if any, from both the tx and rx channels?  Do you expect us to debug hardware by blog?

Comment: I should state for the record that I am very new to CAN.

The output pins from the board are wired to a make-shift board which terminates as recommended (with 120 ohms on the ends).  Attached to this is the NI USB-8472s, set to "listen only", which is supposed to detect and display transmissions (using MAX). Indeed there could end up being a hardware problem, but I have no way of knowing at this point so I'm ensuring that at least the software is sound.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems. My problem was in bad selection of comm parameters (timequantums and prescaler)

I debug it in this way:

- I checked, that RSS pin of CAN transceiver (I used MCP 2551 I/P)
- I switched it to loopback and with osciloscope check output signal on TX channel and on CANH to CANL (if the output is configured properly)
- I looked to RCC configuration - the prescaler of APB1 clock has been changed to 2 (I excepted 4)

Answer (score 1):

For a successful transmission, the CAN controller expects an 'acknowledge' bit which is part of the CAN protocol. If your CAN monitor (by NI) is in listen mode, there will not be an acknowledge-bit(!), and thus you don't get an indication of a successfull transmission at the sending end.

Answer (score 0):

GPIO_Remap2_CAN1 remaps the CAN1 peripheral to PD0 and PD1, not PB8 and PB9. You want GPIO_Remap1_CAN1.

Answer (score 0):

STD peripheral library is deprecated, but since I couldn't find any better examples, I used your not working code as a base.
Initially, I had the same behavior that it worked only in loopback.
After removing remapping to pins PB8 and PB9 **and** setting high speed GPIO for TX pin it started working. Here are my GPIO settings for PA11 and PA12

```
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
/* Configure CAN pin: RX */
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_11;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IPU;
GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

/* Configure CAN pin: TX */
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_12;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = **GPIO_Speed_50MHz**;
GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);
```

The rest I kept the same. (Except changing `CANx` to `CAN1`).